# How to assign same value in multiple times

Tags: javascript, variables, assign

I have multiple times in my script, when I need to assign some long value to target variable. For example:

```
var longVar;

// Now some switch´s case
case:
    longVar = "Some value, which is very, very long";
    break;

// Another case in another switch, so cannot be used writing cases side by side
case:
    longVar = "Some value, which is very, very long";
    break;
```

But it is not too practic. I am currently setting value with function:

```
case:
    setVariable();
    break;

function setVariable() {
    longVar = "Some value, which is very, very long";
}
```

which is (in my opinion) better than writing the value every time. Is it good, or is better, for example, this?:

```
var valueOfLongVar1 = "Some value, which is very, very long";

// Then in cases
case:
    longVar = valueOfLongVar1;
    break;
```

Please, is better function() solution, second variable solution, or another one? Thanks for reply

Comment: A single static string in an outer variable would make more sense to me. But usually there's no good reason to use `switch` at all, I'd avoid it entirely if I were you, it's verbose and error-prone

Comment: It's completely dependent on context and/or opinion, so it's off topic here.

Comment: Best to not use `switch` at all.

Comment: And what to use. If?

Comment: Personally I always prefer `if-else` over `switch`, but this is mostly a matter of taste. However, if you find yourself with a long list of `if-else` (or `case` statements) then it may be time to restructure the code a bit... E.g. use an array or object to contain the options and then just get the appropriate data by key, or extract stuff into classes, or some other technique...

Comment: I see what you're getting at. I would use an object and use keys to look up the lengthy variables. Like `if (statementOne) { longVar = dict["keyOne"] } else if { (statementTwo) { longVar = dict["keyTwo"] }` and then have `dict["keyOne"]` be `"long string...."`. The preferred way would be to create a key from the arguments, and then use that key to look up in the `dict` object.

Comment: Try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ because that site is better suited for this kind of "how can I write clean code" questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for replies, thanks for link to codereview, I will try it next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign variables multiple times it's the best to assign the variable's trough constants.

You shouldn't use methods like you described it.

Updated: Code Snippet

```
const staticText = 'hello world'

let variableText = staticText
```

Comment: Could you please share a code snippet?